# C : Singly linked list sorting segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, linked-list

```
void List_sort (struct nodeStruct **headRef){
    struct nodeStruct *tempNode = *headRef;
    struct nodeStruct *nextNode, *smallestNode;
        while (tempNode != NULL){
            nextNode = tempNode->next;
            smallestNode = tempNode;
            while (nextNode != NULL){
                if (nextNode->item < smallestNode->item) {
                    smallestNode = nextNode->next;
                }
                nextNode = nextNode->next;
            }
            int tempInt = tempNode->item;
            tempNode->item = smallestNode->item;
            smallestNode->item = tempInt;
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }   
}
```

Don't know why it's generating a seg fault, there should be no edits to NULL.
`Segmentation fault. 0x00000000004008d4 in List_sort (headRef=0x7fffffffe458) at list.c:130 130 tempNode->item = smallestNode->item;`
Anyone know why it's doing this?

**Update:**
Performed the suggestions and no more seg fault, however does not sort correctly.

```
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 7
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 6
Value: 5
Value After Sort: 1
Value After Sort: 2
Value After Sort: 4
Value After Sort: 3
Value After Sort: 5
Value After Sort: 6
Value After Sort: 7
```

Comment: the `if(tempNode == NULL) {} else {...` check before `while(tempNode != NULL)` is redundant.

Comment: in `while (nextNode != NULL){ if (nextNode->item < smallestNode->item) smallestNode = nextNode->next;`, `nextNode->next` may be `NULL`, causing `smallestNode` to be `NULL` afterwards. I'd say the offending line should be `smallestNode = nextNode` instead.

Comment: @EOF jesus christ, could not see that small mistake. Thank you

Comment: It's always the small ones which trip one up...

Comment: Is there a reason not to close this as 'off-topic, trivial typo'?

Comment: Is there a reason to be so trivial?

Comment: Ideally you don't want to swap item values. Rather you want to rearrange list elements by modifying their pointers. This makes the size of the underlying item a non-factor in the sorting algorithm.  [something like this](http://pastebin.com/9AhcQEE1), though a merge-sort would preform much better for sizable lists. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't right:

```
            if (nextNode->item < smallestNode->item) {
                smallestNode = nextNode->next;
            }
```

it should be:

```
            if (nextNode->item < smallestNode->item) {
                smallestNode = nextNode;
            }
```